Icomoon - switching from node-sass to sass - good way
at the moment I have hundred websites using icomoon. The system builds styles using node-sass - we want to switch to the sass package. And here comes the problem:
Sometimes, to insert an icon, we use extend, which is not possible in sass package:
.simple-class {
   @extend %font-icomoon;
   @extend .icon-arrow-down:before;
}

When I use the sass package - I get an error:

How are you dealing with this?
I have several hundred pages and I need to edit it somehow so as not to go through each page manually.

On the example code you shared you use @extend .icon-messenger:before;, but on the error it's @extend .icon-arrow-down:before;. Does it mean you have several cases like this? These befores contain different styles from each others?

I corrected it to match the description. However, the problem occurs globally on every icon.

It doesn't answer my questions. I have an answer for the code you shared, but it may not work for you if you have too many of similar piece of code everywhere.

All my websites use icomoon. In some cases it loads icons in a rather unusual way - by loading them into CSS. In node-sass I could extend normally to a pseudo element, but in sass I get this error.
Yes, I have to use many more of these, these are not just two examples, the error is simply the same.
